# How to show that $f(z) = f(i)$

Tags: complex-numbers

Exercise problem. I do not need a full solution because I am trying to solve myself. Just a hint would be great.
Let $f$ be a polynomial with real coefficients. How to show that $f(z) = f(i)$ for every complex $z$?

[image]

Comment: Checked it. I typed in the problem statement word by word exactly like in the book.

Comment: @fade2black What's the book?

Comment: Was it perhaps "with real values" instead of "with real coefficients"?

Comment: @DanielFischer Nice guess.

Comment: Tom M. Apostol, Calculus (Volume 1), 2nd Edition.

Comment: @fade2black What section is it in?

Comment: @Git Gud 9.Complex Numbers

Comment: @fade2black I found it. It's wrong as Panda pointed out. Reading $(b)$ I guess the problem is supposed to be to show that $f(z)=f(\overline z)$.

Comment: @GitGud A typo in the book, if I understand correctly?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yeah. I edited my comment above. Read it.

Comment: @GitGud That should be $f(z) = \overline{f(\overline{z})}$.

Comment: @Panda Turn your comment into an answer so this doesn't show as unanswered?

Comment: @Daniel Both our RHSs are equal.

Comment: @Daniel Fische Do you mean by "with real  values" that the polynomial takes only real values?

Comment: @GitGud I see only one conjugation in yours, and two conjugations in mine.

Comment: @fade2black Yes, that's what I meant. That would imply that it is constant.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand quite well the answer for a) in the book. But my approach (for the part a ) is to use the properties $\overline{z_1 + z_2} = \overline z_1 + \overline z_2 $ and $\overline{z_1*z_2} = \overline{z_1}*\overline{z_2}$, and induction on degree of polynomials.

Base step: $deg(f) = 0$. Let $f(x) = a$. Then $f(z) = a = \overline a = \overline{f(\overline{z})}.$

Induction: $f(x) = a_nx^n + \hat{f}(x)$, where $deg(\hat{f}) < n$.

$f(z) = a_nz^n + \hat{f}(z)$

$\overline{f(\overline{z})} = \overline{a_n(\overline z)^n + \hat{f}(\overline{z})} = \overline{a_n(\overline z)^n} + \overline{\hat{f}(\overline{z})} = a_n\overline{(\overline{z})^n} + \overline{\hat{f}(\overline{z})} = a_n(\overline{\overline{z}})^n + \overline{\hat{f}(\overline{z})} = a_nz^n + \overline{\hat{f}(\overline{z})}$.

But  $\hat{f}(z)=\overline{\hat{f}(\overline{z})}$ by assumption. So, $f(z) = \overline{f(\overline{z})}$.