# Strange property of polynomial functions. Is this a typo in the book?

Tags: complex-numbers

There's one Apostol's Exercise that asks to show that if $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is a polynomial function with real coefficients, then $f(z)=f(i)$ for every complex number $z \in \mathbb{C}$. But I'm certain that this is false, because it would be saying that every polyonomial is constant. And indeed, finding a counterexample is pretty straightforward. Let $f(z)=1+z+z^2$ and compute $f(1+i) =2+3i$ and on the other hand $f(i)=i$ which are clearly different.

Since the seccond item of the exercise asks to show that using this fact we can prove that the complex zeroes of $f$ occur at pairs of complex conjugates, I've managed to replace the first question by proving that $f(z)=f(\bar{z})$ for every $z$.

Is my conclusion correct? Is this really a typo?

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: It is a typo, but the correct equation would be $f(\overline{z})  = \overline{f(z)}$.

Comment: Yes, there was a question about this exact issue some time ago.

Comment: The equation $f(\overline{z}) = \overline{f(z)}$ holds if and only if all coefficients are real.

Comment: Yes @DanielFischer, I've checked here and already found a much simpler way to prove it. Thanks for the the help!

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431136/how-to-show-that-fz-fi) it is. I'll vote to close this one as a duplicate.